# Communication with Apple failed. Your developer account needs to be updated. Please visit Apple Developer Registration

Tags: ios, xcode

When I check auto sing in in Xcode signing and capabilities I am getting the error as "Communication with Apple failed.
Your developer account needs to be updated.  Please visit Apple Developer Registration."

Done research on this but didn't find a single site explains the problem and how to solve it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

did you try to log in to developer.apple.com? probably there is some new agreement you need to approve.

Comment: That did it for me, developer.apple.com! It wasn't enough to log into appstoreconnect.apple.com and accept the agreement there. Apple must have a well-paid UX specialist working to make all the interactions most difficult and confusing for the developers.